# ExtJS 4.2 -Error the black background after hidden menu

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a proplem with my Menu toolbar, When I hover menu, it leaves a black background until refresh page. It is reproducible only in Chrome.

[Image Error Description](http://nx0.upanh.com/b5.s37.d3/67ce1578b50d6347b339898bcd4d941f_55969890.capture.png)

Comment: 1. Link is broken. 2. Show your code.

Comment: my code is very long. it is difficult to show >"<

Comment: Localize the problem. No one will help you otherwise because there could be multiple ways leading to same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with Chrome 27.x. A workaround for that: disable Chrome's hardware acceleration when available.

Go to Chrome's settings -> Show advanced settings... -> uncheck the "Use hardware acceleration when available" and restart browser.

Worked for me...

Comment: bug is fixed.. Thanks very much

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a flash video on my extjs 4 application.
What fixed it was setting hideMode to 'display' on the menu.